# Obtaining one probability distribution function from two other PDFs contained in vectors

Tags: matlab

I have two vectors. The first vector contains the PDF of random variable A, and the second contains the PDF of random variable B. Can I use the two vectors to obtain the PDF of random variable C, where C = A - B? If so, how?

Comment: Supposing I don't have access to the formulas generating the PDF data, but the PDF data is very fine grained...

Answer (score 1):

The PDF of the sum of 2 random variables is the convolution of their PDF's.
Now, since you have the Subtraction you need to think what is the PDF of -B (This is easy).

So, in MATLAB you just need to use the [`conv`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html) function.

#### Distribution of -B

If B has value B with probability p, then -B has value -b with probability p.
Namely we need to reflect the PDF -> Probabilities of value b become the probabilities of value -b.

Comment: Is it really as simple as:

C = conv(A,-1*B)

Comment: Wait, no the distribution is the same but the values corresponding to the probabilities are multiplied by -1.

Comment: My "solution" is clearly not correct. I could use more help.

Comment: Also, you may need to renormalize after convolution, so that the area is 1